# Broken paths on taxonomies after changing permalink to post name

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, 404-error

I have a custom taxonomy. I was able to access the list of items with term foo in taxonomy bar at `mysite.dev/?bar=foo`. I then changed my permalink options from the default to "post name". I can no longer access my taxonomies at `/?bar=foo` nor at `/bar/foo`, which is what it directs me to when I go (via the dashboard) to Posts > bar > foo > View. I get a WP 404 (not an Apache 404).

My .htaccess contains only

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and I have tried the MySQL query `delete from wp_options where option_name="rewrite_rules"` followed by re-saving the permalink settings. There was no change.

Yes, I have cleared caches, via the command line: `wp cache flush`

The taxonomy is registered in functions.php:

```
    // Hook to run the function on init
    add_action('init', 'register_taxonomy_topic');

    function register_taxonomy_bar() {
      register_taxonomy(
          'bar', 
          array('post'),
          array(
              'label' => __('Bar'),
              'show_ui' => true,
              'hierarchical' => false,
              'capabilities' => array(
                  'manage_terms' => 'administrator',
                  'edit_terms'   => 'administrator',
                  'delete_terms' => 'administrator',
              )
          )
      );
    }
    add_action('init', 'register_taxonomy_bar');
```

`var_dump($wp_query['request'])` gives me `SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'barfoo' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC` so I can see it's looking for a post called "barfoo" instead of posts with term "foo" in taxonomy "bar".

I've tried registering the same taxonomy in exactly the same way in the twentyfourteen theme that comes with Wordpress, and I get the same problem. The plugins I have active are: Advanced Custom Fields, Advanced Custom Fields: Nav Menu Field, Advanced Custom Fields Pro, Enhanced Media Library, Google XML Sitemaps, Redirection, SVG Support, The Events Calendar, and Timber. I've tried to disable Redirection to see if that's the problem but it won't allow me to disable it.

I've tried updating everything to the latest version which went smoothly but didn't fix this problem.

What causes this and how do I fix it?

Comment: what does your taxonomy registration code look like? also `var_dump($wp_query)` in the template to see what WordPress is looking for.

Comment: In which template?

Comment: the template that loads when you try to view a term. if you look at the query vars and SQL, you'll see what WordPress is trying to query for.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't get that far.

Comment: I meant whatever template is served for the 404, 404.php or index.php

Comment: Or hook a function to template_redirect and var dump the query there

Comment: Added the request info to the question.

Comment: what happens if you add the `rewrite` argument to your taxonomy registration and set the slug to `bar`?

Comment: No change when I add rewrite.

Comment: I've never seen this sort of issue, the fact that the slash is removed is very strange. I'll guess your theme is doing something wrong, or possibly a plugin. hard to say without seeing all of the code.

Comment: your code works in a new install using twentyfourteen, so it's likely one of your plugins breaking things. you'll have to disable all of them and reenable one at a time to determine what's causing it.

Comment: I tried to do that but I was not able to disable most of them, separate problem.

Answer (score 0):

I added a rewrite rule manually.

```
  add_rewrite_rule('^bar([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$','index.php?bar=$matches[1]','top');
```

right after

```
add_action('init', 'register_taxonomy_bar');
```

in functions.php.

But Wordpress is SERIOUSLY DENSE in translating `/bar/foo/` to `barfoo?bar=foo` and I don't know how to get around this nonsensical "barfoo" in the path. I also have no idea what it'll do to paging. Also this has to be defined for each and every custom taxonomy.

Nevertheless, it works, sort of.